# How to use image as a droppable element inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, droppable, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-droppable

I have an image inside div which acts as droppable.
I want to call drop function when dragging element and hover over the image.
I did it but drop function is not getting called smoothly.
Below is my html code

```
  <div id="divRecycle"><img id="imgRecycle" src="Images/RecycleBin.jpg"/></div>
```

Below is the css used.

```
 .recycle-hover {
    padding: 10px;
    border:  2px dashed orange;
}
```

Below is the javascript code

```
function MakeRecycleBinDivDroppable() {
$("#imgRecycle").droppable({
    accept: ".sections,.cart-item",
    hoverClass: 'recycle-hover',
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    drop: function (event, ui) {



        //check if the draggable element is a section or only a product.
        if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass("sections")) {
            //it is a section, we will delete the section and its products

        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle showing the issue?

Comment: what  does `not called smoothly` mean? Provide a demo that replicates your issue

Comment: I want to trigger the drop event whenever the dragged elemnt is hover over the image.
Now when the mouse is not over image but at random place the drop event occurs.

Comment: Why do you need `helper` and `cursor` options in droppable? jsFiddle example would be useful.